# Solving a Type of System of Cubic Equations

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, cubics

Is there a closed-form solution to the following type of system of cubic equations?
$$
x_j=\sum_{i=1}^na_{ij}x_i^3,\quad\forall\,j=1,...,n
$$
Here the $a_{ij}$'s are constants, and the $x_i$'s are the variables.

Comment: It seems that $n=2$ is awful enough.

Comment: $n=2$ actually reduces to a quartic in $x_j^2$ so technically it has closed form solutions, albeit not pretty. No such luck for $n \gt 2$ though, at least not for arbitrary $a_{ij}$.